# React-native converting getInitialState (ES5) to constructor (ES6) "ListView)

Tags: listview, constructor, ecmascript-6, react-native

Really get in to React-native but running into some issues when converting getInitialState to constructor. I working on a ListView where I rows are swipeable. It works with getInitialState but not with a constructor.

The converted code:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
    StyleSheet,
    ListView,
    Text,
    View,
} = React;

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2',
        flex: 1,
    },
    listview: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    li: {
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderBottomColor: '#eee',
        borderColor: 'transparent',
        borderWidth: 1,
        paddingLeft: 16,
        paddingTop: 14,
        paddingBottom: 16,
    },
    liText: {
        color: '#333',
        fontSize: 16,
    },
    statusbar: {
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        height: 22,
    }
})

var btnsTypes = [
    {text: 'Primary', type: 'primary',},
    {text: 'Secondary', type: 'secondary',},
    {text: 'Delete', type: 'delete',}
]


var rows = [
    {
        text: "Buttons swipe left",
        right: btnsTypes,
    },
    {
        text: "Buttons swipe left",
        right: btnsTypes,
    }
]

//  include react-native-swipeout
var Swipeout = require('react-native-swipeout')


//  example swipout app
class swipeoutExample extends React.Component {

    constructor(){
        super()
        var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => true})

        this.state = {
            dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(rows),
            scrollEnabled: true
        };
    }


//  set scrolling to true/false
    _allowScroll (scrollEnabled) {
        this.setState({ scrollEnabled: scrollEnabled })
    }

//  set active swipeout item
    _handleSwipeout (rowID) {
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            console.log(rowID)
            if (i != rowID) rows[i].active = false
            else rows[i].active = true
        }
        this._updateDataSource(rows)
    }

    _updateDataSource (data) {
        this.setState({
            dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(data)
        })
    }

    _renderRow (rowData: string, sectionID: number, rowID: number) {
        return <Swipeout
            left={rowData.left}
            right={rowData.right}
            rowID={rowID}
            sectionID={sectionID}
            autoClose={rowData.autoClose}
            backgroundColor={rowData.backgroundColor}
            close={!rowData.active}
            onOpen={(sectionID, rowID) => this._handleSwipeout(rowID)}
            scroll={event => this._allowScroll(event)}>
            <View style={styles.li}>
                <Text style={styles.liText}>{rowData.text}</Text>
            </View>
        </Swipeout>
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.statusbar}/>
                <ListView
                    scrollEnabled={this.state.scrollEnabled}
                    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                    renderRow={this._renderRow}
                    style={styles.listview}/>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

module.exports = swipeoutExample;
```

The error message:

[image: The error message:]

The getInitialState that works:

```
var swipeoutExample = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        //  datasource rerendered when change is made (used to set     swipeout to active)
        var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (row1, row2)    => true})

        return {
            dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(rows),
            scrollEnabled: true
        }
    }
```

I have tried everything and everything should be the same, but as always it isnt. Hope anyone can help. Have tried everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is not related with `getInitalState`. The thing is in ES6 classes React doesn't bind your methods to `this`. So your `_renderRow` method is called with the wrong context.

You can fix it by adding the following in the `constructor`

```
constructor() {
    super()
    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => true})
    this.state = {
        dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(rows),
        scrollEnabled: true
    };

    this._renderRow = this._renderRow.bind(this); // <- now your method always save context of this class
}
```

Comment: THANKS. Very helpful